# Looking for missing shared library

Tags: linux, fortran, shared-libraries, fortran90, netcdf

On a Linux system, I am trying to run a Fortran program that makes use of some shared libraries (netCDF libs, if that makes a difference).  Before I run, I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so that it points to the location of my libraries.  Then I run the executable and I quickly get the error

> ../my_program: error while loading shared libraries: libnetcdff.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Now, I double check the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and then cd to it and find plain as day

> $ ls *ff*
>
> $ libnetcdff.a  libnetcdff.la  libnetcdff.so  libnetcdff.so.0  libnetcdff.so.0.0.0

So the libnetcdff is absolutely present.

Could anyone point me to the problem?

The one thing that has occurred to me is that the executable seems to want to find libnetcdff.so.5, while the library that is present is actually libnetcdff.so.0.  Is that the problem?  If so, is there a way to convince the executable to not insist on "5"?  Alternatively, would a link from libnetcdff.so.0 to libnetcdff.so.5 solve the problem?  (I don't have permissions in the directory, BTW, which is why I haven't tried that yet.)

Environment info: CentOS machine, code compiled with gfortran.  And yes, when I compiled, my `-L` flags were pointing to the same directory that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` points to.

Thanks.

Comment: Create a symlink to libnetcdff.so.5 from libnetcdff.so.0. It should work...

Comment: Deleted my comment because I saw my mistake.  Your idea works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A library link should work. Since you mention that you do not have root/sudo access, what you can do is link in a file you *do* have access in:

```
ln -s /path/to/libnetcdff.so.0 /path/you/have/access/to/libnetcdff.so.5
```

And then add in the `/path/you/have/access/to/` in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Tried that.  Didn't go as planned.  Please see my reply to iamauser above.  Any ideas as to what went wrong are most welcome.

Comment: Appreciate your edit.  The only thing is that the two stars in the ls line really are two stars and not a formatting tag, and should be left in place.  I don't know how to do a "re-edit".

Comment: Ignore my first comment.  I saw my mistake.  Your idea worked.  Thanks.

Comment: Curious, I do not actually recall deleting those asterisks (I know they're important), but the edit log shows I did delete them. Glad I could help though!